# Get type instance from string in Python

Tags: python

So, I need to cast a value to a given type:

```
if 'int' == type_name:
    value = int(value)
elif 'str' == type_name:
    value = str(value)
...
```

Is there a way to do that generically? E.g.:

```
type_instance = get_type_instance(type_name)
value = type_instance(value)
```

I'm using Python 2.7, but would be interested in a Python 3.X solution as well.

**Update:**

Here's the solution I'm using:

```
class Token:

    def __init__(self, type_name, value):
        self.type = type_name
        self.value = __builtins__[type_name](value) # not safe
```

This is just a toy parser. **Don't use in production!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need only `__builtins__` types you can do

```
value = getattr(__builtins__, type_name)(value)
```

Comment: clever ... I'm not sure that I like it, but definitely clever (+1)

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it allows `"eval"` for the `type_name` The `dict`-based version allows (in fact, requires) programmer control over what conversions are allowed.

Comment: This is what I was after. I know it's not safe, but I was curious if it could be done. Thanks!

Comment: @larsmans, perhaps you could first check that `type(getattr(__builtins__, type_name))  is type`? That will prevent `eval` from being called.

Comment: @Kevin: that fixes some issues, but it's still hacky and unreliable. E.g., `file` is a type in Python 2, so this can be used to open files, not just lexically cast strings. (Also, the fact that `enumerate` and `reversed` are types is an implementation detail of CPython.)

Comment: In the repl, `__builtins__` is a module, but in scripts, it's a dict, so I have to use `__builtins__[type_name]`. Weird.

Comment: @scribu: that doesn't sound right.  How are you running your scripts?

Comment: @NedBatchelder: `python myscript.py` (Python 2.7.3). The line is in an `__init__()` method, if that matters.

Comment: like @mgilson said, clever, but should be reflection, wonder if they updated this yet.

Answer (score 7):

Build a dict

```
TYPES = {
  'int' : int,
  'str' : str,
...
}

value = TYPES[type_name](value)
```

Comment: you should suggest reflection to the good people of python. somehow function parameters can be typed using strings, but this problem doesn't seem solved except through grow your own solutions like this which are tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified `float64` in an earlier version of the question, I assumed you were also interested in getting numpy types. If so, the following function should solve this:

```
def can_typecast(type, value):        
    try:
        tp = getattr(__builtins__, type)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            np = __import__('numpy')
            tp = getattr(np, type)
            if not isinstance(tp, type):
                raise ValueError('type string is not a type')
        except AttributeError:
            raise ValueError('Invalid type specified')
        except ImportError:
            raise ValueError('Numpy not found')
    try:
        tp(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True
```

What this does is it first looks to see if the given type name can be resolved to a built-in type. If that fails, it looks to see if the type name can be found in numpy *and* if it is a valid type object and if so, tries the cast operation on that.